# Dynamics AX 2009: Displaying a name instead of an ID in a lookup field

Tags: lookup, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I am creating a project in AX 2009 on a form. There is a lookup field called "SubsPersonName", which performs a lookup on the ContactPerson table using the following method.

```
public void lookup()
{
    boolean ret;
    Query                   query;
    QueryBuildDataSource    querybuilddatasource;
    QueryBuildRange         querybuildrange;
    SysTableLookup          sysTableLookup;
    CustInvoiceAccount      _thisinvoiceaccount     = CustTable::find(CustTable::find(TTN_CustVendSubscriptions.AccountNum).InvoiceAccount).PartyId;
    CustAccount             _thisaccountnum         = CustTable::find(TTN_CustVendSubscriptions.AccountNum).PartyId;
    ;

    //TODO: Lookup value should read ContactPerson.Name, not ContactPerson.ContactPersonId
    sysTableLookup = SysTableLookup::newParameters(tablenum(ContactPerson), this);
    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldnum(ContactPerson, Name));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldnum(ContactPerson, ContactPersonId), true);
    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldnum(ContactPerson, CustAccount));
    sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldnum(ContactPerson, VendAccount));
    query = new Query();
    querybuilddatasource = query.addDataSource(tablenum(ContactPerson));
    querybuildrange = querybuilddatasource.addRange(fieldnum(ContactPerson, Name));
    querybuildrange = querybuilddatasource.addRange(fieldnum(ContactPerson, OrgPartyId));
    if (!_thisinvoiceaccount)
        _thisinvoiceaccount = _thisaccountnum;
    querybuildrange.value(strfmt("%1,%2", _thisinvoiceaccount,_thisaccountnum));
    sysTableLookup.parmQuery(query);
    sysTableLookup.performFormLookup();
}
```

The code above works fine, but I need to adjust it slightly. The value that needs to be inserted into the database is ContactPerson.ContactPersonId as per this code, but I would like the field in the form to display ContactPerson.Name.

I realise that I can use a display method to show this, as per this question: [Axapta: Lookup field display the string value instead of the ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716694/axapta-lookup-field-display-the-string-value-instead-of-the-id), but that will involve an unnecessary extra field, which I'd like to avoid if possible.

Please could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

In order to make the ContactPersonId field invisible in the lookup, but still keep it as the return value, change the class `SysTableLookup` method:

```
void addLookupfield(fieldId _fieldId, boolean _returnItem = false, boolean _visible = true)
{
   lookupItems += [[_fieldId, _returnItem, '', _visible]];
}
```

Also change the `buildGrid` method to change the field visibility.

Then change your code like this:

```
sysTableLookup.addLookupfield(fieldnum(ContactPerson, ContactPersonId), true, false)
```

See also [Axaptapedia](http://www.axaptapedia.com/index.php?title=Lookups).

Comment: Very thanks @Jan B. Kjeldsen can you explain better how I have to do in buildGrid method. I have same problem. Thanks in advice. I appreace your help!

Comment: Make the `ContactPersonId` field invisible.

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to hiding the `ContactPersonId` in the calling form then have a look at the `CustTable` form in the "Contact" tab page.

As stated in the forms `ClassDeclaration`:

> > The field `contactpersonId` is hiddeen on the form design, but must be avalible
> >     in order to make it possible to have lookup on contact name

The field `editContactPersonName` has a lookup referring to the hidden `contactpersonId` field:

```
void lookup()
{;
    ContactPerson::lookupCustContactPerson(contactPersonId, custTable.AccountNum, this, custTable.ContactPersonId);
}
```